# ZK how to show 300 list header at one time

Tags: java, list, header, zk

I have table with 300 columns. I can show columns  but zk tries to fit them on my current window. And each headers like inside others. Is there any way yo show headers with scroll bars? With fixed size like TOAD editor.

Comment: You should only ever try and fill one screens worth of data for a user. No one is going to read 10 screen fulls of data. Ask yourself if lots is good why doesnt Google show 10 screens of results when you search ? Answer because its bad design and a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem  using like this

```
        <listbox id="listModel" rows="20"
                                    fixedLayout="true" span="true" mold="paging" pageSize="20">
                                    <listhead>
                                        <listheader id="${each}"
                                            label="${each}" width=" 250px"
                                            forward="onDoubleClick=onRemoveFromHeader"
                                            forEach="${comboModelColumns}" visible="false" />
                                        <custom-attributes
                                            headers="${each}" />


                                    </listhead>
                                    <listitem
                                        forEach="${listValues}">
                                        <listcell
                                            forEach="${listValues[forEachStatus.index]}"
                                            label="${each}" />
                                    </listitem>

                                </listbox>
```

But problem is I can see scrolbar-x  on IE but on Firefox or Chrome it sets  overflow hidden. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the document about [grid with hflex](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Grid%27s_Columns_and_Hflex) which is enhanced since ZK 5.0.6 version.
To be honest, 300 columns shown in a grid seem not to be a good design for a user to navigate the grid, and it may cause some performance penalty.